# Tensorflow: tf.strings.split()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to Python and AI. I'm trying to do a hello world AI.

But I have a question regarding the code.
The path is "C:\ABC\AAC\data\as001.jpg" || "C:\ABC\AAC\data\wb001.jpg"

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import pathlib
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
print(tf.__version__)
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
SIZE = 250
CLASS_NAMES = ['Asparagus','White Bread']
data_dir = pathlib.Path().home().joinpath('Desktop', 'tmp', 'data')
CLASS_NAMES = np.array(['White Bread','Asaparagus'])

list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir/'*'))


def get_label(path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(path, os.path.sep)
    # 1. print(parts[-1])
    return parts[-1]

def decode_img(img):
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [SIZE, SIZE])
    return tf.reshape(img, [-1, 250, 250, 3])

def process(path):
    label = get_label(path)
    img =  tf.io.read_file(path)
    img = decode_img(img)
    return img, label

labeled_ds = list_ds.map(process)
for image, label in labeled_ds:
    #2. print(label)

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(labeled_ds, epochs = 5, steps_per_epoch = 2)
```

I'm trying to understand why Print #1 prints Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=string) but Print #2 prints the actual value tf.Tensor(b'as001.jpg', shape=(), dtype=string)

Also, I'm trying to map the values (wb0 to 0 and as0 to 1) in process function but I can't seem to extract the value from part[-1].

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Short version: use `tf.print` instead of `print`.

Long version: Aha - `print` in `tensorflow`. First note that there is also a `tf.print`. The difference between the two, is that `print` is not included in the tensorflow graph when constructing it, but `tf.print` is. So if you wrap your `get_label` in a `@tf.function` decorator, `print` (the `#1. print`) will only print once, at graph construction time. There's no data in the `tf.Tensor` yet, so it just prints the type. Because you didn't wrap your function in a `@tf.function`, your function executes in eager mode. When executing `tf.data.Dataset` "pipelines" (`.map`,`.take`,...) eagerly, you are (conceptually) constructing the graph every time, thus you print the type of the empty tensor every time.

The second print (the `#2. print`) will print every time, because you are executing that in eager mode, and as you are populating your `tf.Tensor`s with actual data through the `.map(process)` you can see the loaded data. To print the tensor at `#1` at execution instead of construction time, use `tf.print` instead of `print`.